# Is there an upper limit on the amount you can pay by cheque? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, check, regulation

Just curious, assuming I have the necessary funds in an account, is there a hard limit (technical or regulatory) to the amount you can authorise to be paid with a single cheque issued by a UK Bank?

Are there policy limits imposed by individual banks?

If I wrote a valid cheque for, say, £50 Million, what would happen?

Is it the same for other countries' banks (E.G. US Banks) or does it vary?

Comment: Given the decline of cheques and cheque guarantee cards in the UK, are there many retailers (let alone banks) who would even accept a cheque for a non-trivial amount these days?

Answer (score 2):

In theory there is no limit to the value of a cheque that you can write. However, that doesn't mean the bank will honour it even if you have sufficient funds in your account - if it appears out of the ordinary, they may block it on suspicion of fraud or money laundering.

Answer (score 1):

In the united states, they may request a check written by the bank to the other party. I have had to make large payments for home settlements, or buying a car. If the transaction was over a specified limit, they wanted a cashiers check. They wanted to make sure it wouldn't bounce.

I have had companies rebate me money, and say the maximum value of the check was some small value. I guess that was to prevent people from altering the check.

One thing that has happened to me is that a large check I wanted to deposit was held for a few extra days to make sure it cleared. I wouldn't have access to the funds until the deadline passed.

Comment: Don't think you really know what a large personal check is.  The record may be $974,790,317.77, written by Harold Hamm as a divorce settlement: http://www.bankrate.com/financing/banking/the-biggest-personal-check-ever/